# Change position of a html element by jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make a picture slider that when the user's getting to the last picture, the first one will be next.

So, I want to make a situation that on click, my first li will change its position on the html and will be last.

here's my HTML:

```
    <ul>
        <li><img src="img1.jpg" alt="image"></li>
        <li><img src="img2.jpg" alt="image"></li>
        <li><img src="img3.jpg" alt="image"></li>
        <li><img src="img4.jpg" alt="image"></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: many image slider are there with this functionality ,try google

Comment: I have done one simple slider, you can check it on http://jsfiddle.net/waseemmachloy/gYaP8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can help you.

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function(){
    $(this).appendTo( $(this).parent() )
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/h6qfM/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
$('ul li').eq(0).appendTo('ul');
```

or on click:

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    $('ul li').eq(0).appendTo('ul');
});
```